# OSX - Start and Stopping of Nginx error

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew

I install `nginx` via home brew and when i try to start or stop it i get the following error

```
➜  ~  sudo nginx -s stop
nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
➜  ~  sudo nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

**File structure**

```
➜  ~  /usr/local/var/run
➜  run git:(master) ls
nginx
➜  run git:(master) cd nginx
➜  nginx git:(master) ls
client_body_temp fastcgi_temp     proxy_temp       scgi_temp        uwsgi_temp
➜  nginx git:(master)
```

**To check if nginx is running**

```
➜  ~  ps waux | grep nginx
harshamv          963   0.0  0.0  2432772    656 s000  S+    1:32PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn nginx
```

**When i try to run Nginx i get the following error.**

```
➜  ~  nginx
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2015/07/02 13:39:44 [emerg] 1074#0: open() "/usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: It won't start because the 8080 port is in use (opened by some process, possibly nginx but doesn't look like it). `pgrep nginx` will tell you if nginx is still running, and `lsof -i 4tcp |grep 8080` will tell you which process is holding the 8080 port if it's not nginx.

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov yes nginx is running on port 8080 how can i stop it?

Comment: when i run those commands nothing is shown @LeonidShevtsov

Comment: Please run `sudo netstat -lnt | grep :8080`. If the output is empty then there's nothing holding port 8080. Did you run the `lsof` command that was suggested above? If nginx is running you can kill it because the pid file is missing therefore the start/stop script will fail to stop it.

Comment: when i go to localhost:8080 i get the welcome to Nginx screen. When i run `sudo netstat -lnt | grep :8080` and `lsof -i 4tcp |grep 8080` it just goes back to prompt line.

Comment: Oopps. You are running MacOS, therefore ports are not displayed as :8080 when netstat list it. It should be `netstat -lnt | grep \.8080`. Can you also check the output of `sudo lsof -i 4tcp:8080`. This is more direct.

Comment: @alvits both nothing is returned :/ this is so weird

Comment: If `nginx` is running as another user, then `lsof` must be run with privilege using `sudo`. If your system is all messed up, you have to resort to rebooting it.

Comment: @alvits this is only one user in the system. its a fresh install of mac :(

Comment: by running just `lsof` i get a huge list of things running :D

Comment: Even a freshly installed mac will have privileged processes running as root and other uids. If `nginx` is running as `root` or another uid, you can't see its open files. You have to be root or use `sudo`.

Comment: If you truly can't see any `nginx` process and can't identify any process holding up port 8080 using lsof, you probably just need to reinstall your mac.

Comment: @alvits hehe. i had actually done just this week :D

Comment: A simple `ps waux` will show that there are running processes you don't own. If those are missing, your system wasn't built right.

Comment: thats shows my unsername at the start.

Answer (score 0):

There is one case I have met. If you start nginx with a conf file, which looks like `nginx -c my.conf`, you have to stop it with `nginx -s stop -c my.conf`.

In your `my.conf` file, you may use `pid /some_location/nginx.pid;`, and this will generate a pid file at that location, which is not any more the default location at `/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid`, and this is why you cannot stop it.

I think when you met such error, you have an option to check `ps -ef | grep nginx` for its pid, at least can kill it manually.

Answer (score -4):

Mac OS X EI no permission in /usr

solve:

sudo chown -R username run

chmod -R 777 run/

if anyother permission problem

like "xxx" permission,please use "chown" "chmod" command.

in this way my problem sloved!

Comment: This is very bad advice. `chmod 777` is never the correct solution.

Comment: yes,your are right.but in my personal computer chmod 777,it just for testting. in the server side,you can set  the strict permission.